# html table editable and non-editable cells with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

Is there a plugin or way to make certain table columns (not rows) editable and others not editable
with jQuery?

I have seen plugins for clicking on a cell to make it editable, but I mean explicitly making a cell/column editable or not.
I have a way of doing it but it feels like a bit of a hack job.

Here is my function for making a column editable:

```
function isEditable(rowArray, headersArray)
{
    var counter = 0;
    var notEditable = ['product code', 'product'];
    for(i in rowArray){
        counter = 0;
        data = headersArray[i].toLowerCase();
        for(a in notEditable){
            if(data == notEditable[a]){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        if(counter > 0){
            rowArray[i] += 'notEditable';
        }
    }
    return rowArray;
}
```

it compares the header of the cell to an array of predefined values which = a non-editable column.

Then I build the row:

```
function buildHTMLTableRow(row, mutable)
{       
    output = '';
    output += '<tr>';
    for(var i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
    {
        value = trim(row[i]);
        if(mutable){
            index = value.indexOf('notEditable');
            if(index != -1){
                value = value.substring(0, index);
                output += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
            }
            else{
                output += '<td><input size="5" type="text" value="' + value + '" /></td>';
            }
        }
        else{
            output += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
        }
    }
    output += '</tr>';
    return output;
}
```

The `mutable` parameter decides if the row is editable or not, and the `indexOf('noteditable')` decides for the cell(but pretty much column) from the `isEditable` function.

Is there a plugin that does this better, or should I just settle with what I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit this jsFiddle link: [Disable Columns](http://jsfiddle.net/hunTQ/)

Following is the data flow:

1. I have created a row Array named "rowsD". When page loads I am populating my table (id=myData) with these rows.
2. Now creating another array called **disableHeaders** wherein I am passing the headers,
   which you need to disable entire columns.
3. I am calling function **disableFields** passing **disableHeaders** as parameter
4. In the function, first I am fetching the index of the header whose value is equal to the values in **headers** array
5. If I find one, then from **Input** tag I am extracting the **Value** attribute using $(this).find('input') selector
6. Finally I am replacing the current child with **Label** tag passing the extracted Input tags Value
7. You may also comment out disableFields(disableHeaders); line to actually see, how table gets rendered initially

Thank you

Comment: yep that works to, and is probably more reusable as the headers to be disabled are passed as parameters as apposed to being hard coded into the isEditable function like in my method. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually just found that using replaceWith() on a td sets its index to -1 which is bad because I use the index value :(